# Flattening mixed nested monads in cats (composing complex Kleislis)

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I would like to understand how I should compose Kleislis that return "complex" types (e.g. `F[Either[A,B]]`). Here's an example of what I mean:

This is a simple case - given two Kleislis

```
val parseRegistration: Kleisli[Result, Auth.Registration, Auth.Registration] = ???
val hashPassword: Kleisli[Result, Auth.Registration, Auth.Registration] = ???
```

I can compose them in this way:

```
val validateAndHash = parseRegistration andThen hashPassword
```

And all is fine.

However, given more complex Kleisli types (where the return value is an `Either[A, B]`), I'm not able to compose them directly (because I ended up with `F[Either[A,B]]` where a Kleisli expects only `F[A]`).

```
// relevant type definitions
final case class ServiceError(kind: ErrorKind, message: String = "", cause: Option[Throwable] = None)
final type Result[A] = Either[ServiceError, A]
final case class Registration(email: String, password: String)
final case class Registered(session: Session)


val createUser: Kleisli[F, Auth.Registration, Result[Long]] = ???
val createSession: Kleisli[F, Long, Result[Session]] = ???


// does not compile (no overloaded alternatives match the arguments) - I expected this as  
// createUser returns F[Result[Long]] and the createSession Kleisli expects only F[Long]
val createUserAndSession = createUser andThen createSession
```

Ok, so as expected. Then, instead of composing them, I tried simply performing nested maps:

```
val r1 = validateAndHash(info) // Result[Auth.Registration]
val r2 = r1.map(i => createUser(i)) // Either[ServiceError, F[Result[Long]]]
val r3 = r2.map(_.map(_.map(uid => createSession(uid).map(_.map(Auth.Registered.apply)))))
// Now I've got an Either[ServiceError, F[Either[ServiceError, F[Either[ServiceError, Auth.Registered]]]]]
// in r3! I wanted to end up with F[Result[Auth.Registered]]
```

So I've ended up causing increasing nesting and `flatten` doesn't seem to help because `F` and `Result` can't be flattened into each other.

I'm sure this is something the seasoned scala cats programmers encounter all the time, so I'd appreciate it if you could help me understand how I can avoid getting myself into this mess?

EDIT:

I have now defined a function to invert the nested wrapper types so they can then be flattened:

```
  def invert[S, F[_]: Monad, V](e: Either[S, F[V]]): F[Either[S, V]] =
    e match {
      case Left(s) => Monad[F].pure(Left(s))
      case Right(fv) => fv.map(Right(_))
    }
```

This allows me to do this:

```
val r1 = validateAndHash(info)
val r2 = invert(r1.map(i => createUser(i))).map(_.flatten)
val r3 = r2.map( i => invert(i.map(uid => createSession(uid).map(_.map(Auth.Registered.apply)))).map(_.flatten))
val r4 = Monad[F].flatten(r3)
```

Which seems... clumsy? And too specific to `Either`. Is there a cleaner way to do this using something built in to cats?

Comment: `Kleisli` is quite poor at providing automatic composition for different inputs or effects. (There are things like mapF and mapK) That's one of the selling points of ZIO and its approach toward DI through types. There's one monad to rule them all, so it all composes nicely, at the cost of infecting your whole codebase with a specific effect.

Comment: Thanks @MateuszKubuszok. I was hoping to understand how to do it with just cats, but always interested in hearing about alternatives. I'll look into ZIO

Comment: Yeah, if you want to stay with Cats then unfortunately you'll have to use `mapK` and `mapF` manually to align `F` types yourself, so it works better with some ad-hoc composition of several services with the same input or having the same input globally. With ZIO things should be more automagical, but you'll commit to one monad for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather compose values than play with `Kleisli`, especially since `EitherT` makes this pretty simple.

First, let's refactor `createUser` & `createSession` to be normal methods:

```scala
def createUser[F[_]](registration: Registration): F[Result[Long]] = ???
def createSession[F[_]](long: Long): F[Result[Session]] = ???
```

And now let's implement `createUserAndSession`

```scala
import cats.Monad
import cats.data.EitherT

def createUserAndSession[F[_]](registration: Registration)(implicit ev: Monad[F]): F[Result[Session]] =
  EitherT(createUser(registration)).flatMapF(createSession).value
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the issue was I failed to understand what monad transformers are/how they would fit here. I've now refactored away from kleislis to MTs and seen a decent simplification of my code. Slightly out of scope, but would also appreciate your thoughts on pushing `EitherT` down into the function signature - if I control the lower level functions and they are private to the calling scope it feels like I could make them return EitherT rather than casting on use, or is that frowned upon?

Comment: @Orphid hey glad it helped you :) About your question, I actually don't need to use transformers a lot _(mainly because I don't use many typed errors)_ so I don't have a proper insight. However, some more experienced folks like Fabio and Rob recommend keeping the transformers as implementation details _(for example, you can see that I didn't need to wrap `createSession` into `EitherT`)_  - Anyways, why don't you join us in the [**typelevel discord** server](https://discord.gg/XJkubMZE) and you ask that _(and future questions)_ there :) Many people will be happy to provide their advice